# show that T is the discrete topology on X.

Tags: general-topology

Let X be an infinite set and let T be a topology on X in which all infinite subset of X are open . Show that T is the discrete topology on X.

Comment: Add context to your post by sharing your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that every singleton in $X$ is open. Indeed, given any $x \in X$, pick some element $a_1 \in X - \{x\}$. Then pick another element $a_2 \in X - \{x, a_1\}$. Continue inductively to get a countable sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of distinct elements in $X - \{x\}$. (Note: this is implicitly using the axiom of dependent choice.) Observe that:
$$
\{x\} = \{x, a_1, a_3, a_5, \ldots \} \cap \{x, a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots\}
$$
Both sets on the RHS are infinite, and so both sets are open in the given topology. Hence, so is their intersection, as desired.